# How to add filter to <img> when hovering parent <div>

Tags: html, css, sass

I wanted to ask if its possible to set filter on child when hovering the parent
I got this html code:

```
<div class="footer flex">
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/" class="footer-button" target="_blank">
           <img src="assets/imgs/icons/ig.svg" alt="ig">
        </a>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" class="footer-button" target="_blank">
           <img src="assets/imgs/icons/fb.svg" alt="fb">
        </a>
    </div>
```

*everything in SASS
I tried this:

```
.footer-button img:hover
    filter: invert(0.2) sepia(2) saturate(7) hue-rotate(17deg)
```

this sets filter when hovering the img I know that
also tried this

```
.footer-button:hover + .footer-button img
    filter: invert(0.2) sepia(2) saturate(7) hue-rotate(17deg)
```

and this one changes the color of another , I hover ig but it sets filter to fb.
so I dedicated that i could try this

```
.footer-button:hover + img
    filter: invert(0.2) sepia(2) saturate(7) hue-rotate(17deg)
```

and that does nothing

I would like to do that in plain SASS, no JS :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `.footer-button:hover > img`?

Comment: Thanks a lot ! ">" works how I wanted